# Find global minimum in continuos data

Tags: algorithm, search, find, min, continuous

I am a student who is just a beginer in programming. I am trying to find global minimum value of light on cotinuos road. For example, In a curved road, I want to find the minimum value of light that arrives to the middle of the road, without checking every points. Are there any algorithms that finds global minimum value in continuos data and the values are not yet found? Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow please read the following guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

As every light could potentially light on that part of the road there is no easy way to do this.

Comment: Could you please explain more why this is impossible?